# Docker default example dockerfile and layer breakdown

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker. So far, I have followed the default getting started manual from the docker website, as well as watched/read a fair amount of additional info (videos from conferences, internal overview videos and articles) on how docker actually works under the hood (I find it necessary to know, otherwise I feel I push random buttons and expect a miracle). I understand in abstract terms what it does and how it works, but I have some gaps in going from the abstract architecture to actual practical results, and I have a few basic questions.

Host platform: Windows 10

```
docker --version
Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b

wsl --version
WSL version: 2.0.14.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.3803
```

For example, here is my Dockerfile, which is an unchanged getting started tutorial dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

All I did with the image was basically run, stop, remove, create it anew. I didn't get much further than that, because I felt I wanted to know what I actually did.

I decided to check out layers in Docker Desktop. I got curious about layers, and I checked docker desktop layers of my image. Default example layers.

[image: docker desktop layers screenshot]

If I do docker history, I get the following:

```
docker history f2b23ca3d96bcf2b300cb43626072454c87f4284a028860c4703b0354dee7fe5
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
f2b23ca3d96b   4 days ago    EXPOSE map[3000/tcp:{}]                         0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      4 days ago    CMD ["node" "src/index.js"]                     0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      4 days ago    RUN /bin/sh -c yarn install --production # b…   85.3MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      4 days ago    COPY . . # buildkit                             6.49MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      5 days ago    WORKDIR /app                                    0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["node"]                 0B
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entry…   0B
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:4d192565a7220e13…   388B
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --virtual .bui…   7.77MB
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.19     0B
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c addgroup -g 1000 node     && addu…   117MB
<missing>      6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_VERSION=18.19.0     0B
<missing>      10 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>      10 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:1f4eb46669b5b6275…   7.38MB
```

My questions:

1. Why is there multiple CMDs, if it's stated explicitly in the docker documentation, that all but last are ignored?
2. How can I view the full layer entry? Its full text is not shown in Docker Desktop, neither it is shown in the command line. The only way to view full layer content is to stretch docker desktop 3 monitors wide. Still not enough for one of my layers.
3. What is the `<missing>` thing in docker history output, and why do those layers(?) have a great creation date difference? Aren't they supposed to be all at the same time?
4. What is the `# buildkit` thing added to some layers, even tho the dockerfile doesn't have it in seemingly corresponding lines?
5. Some arrows in docker desktop layer view are greyed out, some are not. It seems to correspond to where those layers come from - from my dockerfile or from ...?

It would be very nice if you could walk over docker history output and give a short line by line explanation of every layer entry. I can make a reasonable guess for some, but not for all. I found the description of commands in documentation, but I'm afraid I might misinterpret something, just like I clearly misunderstand docker CMD, which is kinda one per dockerfile, but used multiple times in layers.

Comment: "*My questions:*" - Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I believe all my questions are closely related to command line output and the screenshot (of effectively the same thing). In my opinion, your objections don't apply here. These are all aspects of one and the same thing. I'm merely trying to understand what a list of layers actually shows me.

Comment: Just because they are related by a command (in this case: `docker history`) does not mean they are related in semantics. For example: the multiple `CMD`s may stem from the fact that a hierarchy of "parents" may be at work, and each parent defines its own command, because each parent has a specific use-case in mind. On the other hand, viewing the "full entries" is a question on the command itself, and has nothing to do witht the actual image.

Answer (score 1):

I can take a crack at questions #1, #2 and #5.

Your Dockerfile is layered upon another Dockerfile. The first line `FROM node:18-alpine` pulls layers from a Docker image that is Alpine Linux with node.js installed. You can view [the source for that Dockerfile on Github](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/18/alpine3.19/Dockerfile).

The greyed out arrows in the layer view are layers from that parent Dockerfile.[image: Dockerfile compared]

You can view the "full layer content" on Github. The RUN commands are especially long because they are many commands combined together.

The reason you see multiple CMD layers is because the parent Dockerfile provides one, but you provide one too. The topmost CMD layer overrides, so only yours is used.